# C++ Operator overloading class and a struct

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to do something I'm not entirely sure is even possible. I'm trying to overload an equals operator something like this:

```
Class A //Defined somewhere
Struct B{
   float bobsAge; 
};
B& operator=(A,B){
    A.GetAge("bob",B.bobsAge);

    return B; 
}

Function(getAge){
    A Names;
    B structNames; 

    structNames = Names; 
}
```

I understand that this might not be possible, as I understand the operator= is used to do things such as setting one object of the same type equal to another object.  Or is this possible to do but I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to overload the *assignment operator* However, the standard approach would be to provide a conversion constructor:

```
class A
{
 public:
  A(const B& b) { GetAge("bob", b.bobsAge; }
};
```

And then let that implicit conversion kick in for expressions such as

```
A a;
B b;
a = b; // Assignment: calls A(const B&), and uses A's default assignment operator 
A a2 = b;  // Construction: calls A(const B&) and A(const A&)
```

You could have provided an assignment operator

```
A& operator=(const B&);
```

but it seems unintuitive to allow only assignment from `B` to `A`, and not construction.

Answer (score 3):

`operator=` is an assignment operator and can only be overridden *inside* the class being assigned to. So in your case, it would have to be declared inside `A`.

"Equals operator," that is, `operator==`, is used for comparing two objects for equality.

Answer (score 2):

You can overload `operator=` but it has to be in-class. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B for what can be outside of the class definition.

e.g.

```
class foo {
  foo& operator=(B b) {
    //...
    return *this;
  };
};
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with it though.

Also, it's the assignment operator - don't refer to it as the equals operator.